# Run TamperMokey script on Page Load

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have written a script that is current working in GreaseMonkey on page load. However, when I transfer this script over to TamperMonkey (In Chrome), the Script refuses to run on Page Load.

See Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Redirect_ADFS
// @author      Eskimonian
// @version     2018.08.20
// @description     Auto Redirect ADFS Sites to Internal Login Page
// @run-at      document-end
// ==/UserScript==

window.onload = function Redirect() {
  var currenturl = window.location.href //define current URL
  if(currenturl.indexOf("/adfs") > -1) {
    var newurl = "//" + new URL(document.referrer).hostname + '/admin?saml=off'; //set destination URL
    alert("[Eskimo.1] SAML Site Detected. Redirecting to Internal Login page.")
window.location = newurl
  }
} //redirect URL if the currently existing url contains "adfs" in its pathname
```

What the script does:

Example with script running in background:

Go to: https://www.piercecountywa.gov/

Type /admin: https://www.piercecountywa.gov/admin

Redirects to: https://sas.co.pierce.wa.us/adfs/ls/

My script will then force the page to render the referral URL and add /admin?saml=off to the referral string and reload the page

My Script goes to: https://www.piercecountywa.gov/admin?saml=off

Again, running this in Greasemonkey works, however - I cannot understand how to make it run on start with Tampermonkey.

Any help on understanding WHY this is not working would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you! 
I understand this might be hard to troubleshoot as you cannot test so here is a video of the script working in Greasemonkey.

- https://www.screencast.com/t/1iNr7JcS

Note the immediate redirect from the ADFS login to the internal login form.

Answer (score 8):

In your header, you're using `@run-at document-start`, which according to the [documentation](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php), will inject the script immediately.

Try using `@run-at document-end`, which injects the script when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is dispatched. If you don't have luck with that, try hooking into the `load` event by means of;

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("All resources finished loading!");
});
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load

Comment: This resolved my issue and I very much appreciate the help! :) I would publically mark this up, but it will not visibly show as my reputation is low. Thank you, again!

Comment: @TheEskimonian If it resolved your issue, then please accept it as the accepted answer.

Comment: not working for me (January 2023). i used it as bookmarlet that was moving to  https://lichess.org/training first.